# Telegram bot python — как сделать уведомление или напоминание по нажатию кнопки на определённый день и время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота на питоне и у меня есть трудности в создании уведомления.
У меня такая цель, что есть некая игра. В некой игре проходит два раза в неделю событие в 21:00 и мне нужно написать на питоне, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал кнопку, например, "Включить уведомление", то за 10 минут до начала ему будут приходить уведомления сообщением в эти дни о том, что через 10 минут начнется событие

```
import schedule # Установил библиотеку schedule и импортировал её
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) # Создал, чтобы обрабатывал текст, переходя по кнопкам
def func(message): 
# ...
elif (message.text == "Включить уведомление"): # Когда уже хотел реализовать, ничего не происходит
schedule.every().minutes.do(func)
schedule.every().hour.do(func)
schedule.every().monday.at("20:50").do(func)
schedule.every().tuesday.at("20:50").do(func)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Уведомление включено.", parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spisok = [] #создаём список
spisok.append(message.from_user.id) #Добавляем пользователя в список, если он включил уведомления
#Отправляем уведомления (код нужно поместить в начале)
def obnulenie():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "20:50:00": #проверяем время
        #тут пробегаем циклом по списку пользователей и отправляем им сообщения
thread1 = Thread(target=obnulenie, args=()) #создаём поток
thread1.start() #запускаем поток
```